# Trouble with Enum Field in Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose Enum Field Not Enforcing Values

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!']
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
   validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
},
photo: String,
role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user'
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
   select: false
},
passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      // This only works on CREATE and SAVE!!!
     validator: function(el) {
       return el === this.password;
     },
    message: 'Passwords are not the same!'
    }
  },
passwordChangedAt: Date,
passwordResetToken: String,
passwordResetExpires: Date,
active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
   select: false
}
});
```

This is my userShema. When I try to save a new user without providing a role, it works as a default value "user". But when I save the user with "admin" role, it doesn't work and always return a role as a "user".
[api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZj5s.png)

```
exports.signup = catchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
const newUser = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
});

const token = signToken(newUser._id);

res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
        user: newUser
    }
})});
```

this is my signup function

Comment: Please provide the code of your signup function (anonymised if needed) plus don't show images when you can show actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not declaring `role` in your `Model.create()` function so it will always default to the deafult value of `user`.

You can try just using optional chaining so if `role` is part of the post request it will use it, otherwise it will use the default like so:

```js
const newUser = await User.create({
    role: req.body?.role || 'user'
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
});
```

Alternatively you can just use the `req.body.admin` assignment which will be `undefined` if it's not part of the post request. As such, mongoose will use your default value like so:

```js
const newUser = await User.create({
    role: req.body.role //< will be undefined if not there
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
});
```

You will still get validation because if the `req.body.admin` value is not part of the `enum` array mongoose will throw a validation error.

Comment: Ahh.. that was my stupid mistake. Thanks y'all.

Comment: @akpp there are a few ways to do this kind of thing but this way is pretty straightforward. The only downside is that if you change the default value in your schema then you will need to change your create function. Just something to keep in mind.